# FB Graph API post Backdating does not work on all pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using graph API `v12.0`to add images with backdate.

I'm posting to `{page_id}/photos` endpoint and it works fine on 2 pages - but not on my production page.
On test pages Photos are backdated properly. However, when I try to post to my main page, backdating does not work and all posts have "Just now" date added.
Can't figure out, what's the difference between these 2 pages and my main page - maybe some kind of bug?. Tried all tokens, from temp, through long lived to permanent.
I created 3 Apps. each app works fine on test sites, but not on my main Facebook Page.

Tried with `backdated_time` as string (YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss) and as Unix Timestamp. Also tried adding `created_time` field to request.

What's odd, when photo is on site, I can backdate it manually without a problem. However backdating each photo manually is not solution.

Edit:

I've found, that this site is managed by business account, and other two are managed by personal account. It may be related to this.

Eit2: I also tried creating "system users" for business account, but they cannot create photos.

Comment: Is your app reviewed & in live mode yet?

Comment: It is not. Would it matter however? It can publish to 2 pages, which are also published, just fine. Just one page does not see it. 
The only thing in difference between these 2 and main one is number of existing posts and fans.